# Countdown function isn't actually counting down

Tags: javascript, html, function, counter

1. I have a function in my .js file that is supposed to display a countdown from 10 - 0. Once it hits 0, it should open up a second page. I don't have the part where it opens the page written yet, but that isn't my current problem. My problem is that the countdown will display the number 1, and do nothing else. I'm not really sure why.
2. Here's the countdown function

   ```js
   function startCountdown() {
       for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--) { 
           document.getElementById("countdown").value = i;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Here is the function that calls it

   ```js
   function startAdPage() {
       setInterval(changeAd(), 2000);
       setInterval(startCountdown(), 1000);
   }
   ```
4. Finally, here is the HTML code that it is sending to. Everything is started by the body tag calling the `onload` method. I know that part works, since I have it doing something else that is working properly.

   ```html
   <div id="counter">
       <p>The Central Valley Realtors home page will display in 
       <input type="text" value="" class="countdown"/>
       seconds</p>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: The execution is fast enough for you to see, put an alert box within the loop and you shall see it poping up with expected values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `setInterval` is a function. You're not passing the function, you're calling the function and passing whatever it returns, since you have `()` after the function name.

Also, you're not waiting between updates to the countdown field. Javascript is single-threaded, the page doesn't update until the script returns. You need this:

```
function startAdPage(){
    var curCounter = 10;
    function startCountdown() {
        document.getElementById("countdown").value = curCounter;
        curCounter--;
        if (curCounter == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownInterval);
        }
    }
    setInterval(changeAd, 2000);
    var countdownInterval = setInterval(startCountdown, 1000);

}
```

Comment: For some reason, the text in countdown loads as 1 and never changes

Comment: I just tried it, the only problem I ran into was that you didn't have `id="countdown"` in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop inside of `startCountdown` is running all the way to the end of the loop, so the value ends up 0. Also, you are supposed to pass either an Anonymous function or an unexecuted function to `setInterval` and `clearInterval` without parameters. When you add `()` at the end of a function name you are executing the function. Change the the `<input type='text' class='countdown' />` to `<input type='text' id='countdown' />`, then try the following:

```
function countdown(begin, end, interval, outputElement){
  var repeat = setInterval(function(){
    if(outputElement.innerHTML){
      outputElement.innerHTML = begin--;
    }
    else{
      outputElement.value = begin--;
    }  
    if(begin === end)clearInterval(repeat);
  }, interval);
}
countdown(10, 0, 1000, document.getElementById('countdown'));
```